# vuetify change theme to a custom one

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've been using Vuetify for a few weeks now.
Having read the docs and some posts in that regard I tried to alter the 'dark' theme to suite my needs.

From some reason, I can only alter colours to components by specifically setting their colours of via CSS of course.

my vuetify.js file (under plugins) looks like that:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
import colors from 'vuetify/lib/util/colors';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: colors.purple,
        secondary: colors.grey.darken1,
        accent: colors.shades.black,
        error: colors.red.accent3,
      },
      dark: {
        primary: colors.blueGrey.darken2,
        secondary: colors.blueGrey.lighten2,
        accent: colors.blueGrey.darken3,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

My App.vue file looks like that:

```
  <div>
    <v-app dark>
      <v-tabs background-color="#2c394f" color="white">
        <v-tab to="/deploy">Deploy</v-tab>
        <v-tab to="/dashboard">Dashboard</v-tab>
      </v-tabs>
      <keep-alive>
        <router-view/>
      </keep-alive>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>

<style src="vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"></style>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

As you may notice, I'm using dark theme (in v-app component) and since my theme definitions are not being applied, I've manually set the (for instance) v-tabs component.
Ideally, I'd like to just set the colour of v-tabs using color="primary" or something like that, but if I remove the properties, I'm getting the default theme, which is 'light' in that case.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to set `theme.dark:true` to enable dark for the entire app. 
Then the custom dark colors will be applied..

```
export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    dark: true,
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: colors.purple,
        secondary: colors.grey.darken1,
        accent: colors.shades.black, 
        error: colors.red.accent3,
      },
      dark: {
        primary: colors.blueGrey.darken2,
        secondary: colors.blueGrey.lighten2,
        accent: colors.blueGrey.darken3,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/KGnmtCQYi1)

Comment: That was ridiculously simple. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To extend [Zim answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59455664/6928287), there's also the ability to set it programatically if you want to provide that option to the user using `this.$vuetify.theme.dark //bolean`.

This example may be seen in the documentation https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#theme-provider

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
  }),
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>
          <v-card flat>
            <v-toolbar flat height="72">
              <v-switch v-model="$vuetify.theme.dark" hint="This toggles the global state of the Vuetify theme" inset label="Vuetify Theme Dark" persistent-hint></v-switch>
            </v-toolbar>

            <v-card-text>
              <v-list dark>
                <v-subheader>I inherit dark from my parent</v-subheader>

                <v-list-item v-for="item in items" :key="item">
                  <v-list-item-title v-text="item"></v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list>

              <v-divider class="mb-y"></v-divider>
              <v-theme-provider root>
        <v-list>
          <v-subheader>
            <span>I inherit from the root</span>

            <strong>&nbsp;$vuetify.theme.dark</strong>
          </v-subheader>

          <v-list-item
            v-for="item in items"
            :key="item"
          >
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item"></v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-theme-provider>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
      <v-footer>Footer without app</v-footer>
    </v-app>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 3:

1. plugins/vuetify.ts:

```
// custom Themes
const customLightTheme: ThemeDefinition = {
  dark: false,
  colors: {
    background: import.meta.env.VITE_VUETIFY_LIGHT_BG,
    surface: import.meta.env.VITE_VUETIFY_LIGHT_SURFACE_BG,
    primary: import.meta.env.VITE_VUETIFY_LIGHT_PRIMARY,
    secondary: import.meta.env.VITE_VUETIFY_LIGHT_SECONDARY,
    // error: '#B00020',
    // info: '#2196F3',
    // success: '#4CAF50',
    // warning: '#FB8C00',
    text: import.meta.env.VITE_VUETIFY_LIGHT_TEXT,
  },
};
const customDarkTheme: ThemeDefinition = {
  dark: true,
  colors: {
    background: import.meta.env.VITE_VUETIFY_DARK_BG,
    surface: import.meta.env.VITE_VUETIFY_DARK_SURFACE_BG,
    primary: import.meta.env.VITE_VUETIFY_DARK_PRIMARY,
    secondary: import.meta.env.VITE_VUETIFY_DARK_SECONDARY,
    // error: '#B00020',
    // info: '#2196F3',
    // success: '#4CAF50',
    // warning: '#FB8C00',
    text: import.meta.env.VITE_VUETIFY_DARK_TEXT,
  },
};

function getDefaultTheme() {
  const theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
  if (theme && ["customLightTheme", "customDarkTheme"].includes(theme)) {
    return theme;
  }
  if (theme) localStorage.removeItem("theme");
  return 'customLightTheme';
}

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
  icons: {
    defaultSet: 'mdi',
    aliases,
    sets: {
      mdi,
    },
  },
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: getDefaultTheme(),
    themes: {
      customLightTheme,
      customDarkTheme
    },
  },
});
```

2. in components/switchThemeBtn.vue:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useTheme } from 'vuetify';

const theme = useTheme();

function changeTheme() {
  const customThemes = Object.keys(theme.computedThemes.value).filter(theme => theme.includes("custom"));
  const themeIndex = customThemes.indexOf(theme.global.name.value);
  // console.log("custom", customThemes);

  const preferredTheme = customThemes[themeIndex === customThemes.length - 1 ? 0 : themeIndex + 1];
  theme.global.name.value = preferredTheme;
  localStorage.setItem("theme", preferredTheme);
}
</script>
```